# Making path parameters optional in WebSocket endpoints in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket, endpoint, path-parameter

Given a WebSocket endpoint as follows.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/Push/CartPush/{token}")
public final class CartPush {
    // ...
}
```

The endpoint is able to accept a path parameter `{token}`. The path parameter is however, optional **which is determined dynamically at run-time in Java Script.** Skipping this parameter in JavaScript like the following results in `404`.

```javascript
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/ContextPath/Push/CartPush");
```

> WebSocket connection to
>   `'wss://localhost:8443/ContextPath/Push/CartPush'` failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

It makes the token value compulsory as follows.

```javascript
var token = "token value";
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/ContextPath/Push/CartPush" + "/" + token);
```

In order to exclude all unneeded HTTP methods except `GET` and `POST`, I use the following restrictions or constraints along with Servlet security constraints using appropriate URL patterns and role mappings in `web.xml`.

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Disable unneeded HTTP methods by 403</web-resource-name>

        <url-pattern>/Public/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/Push/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>

        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<deny-uncovered-http-methods/> <!-- Requires Servlet 3.1 -->
```

How to make the given path parameter optional?

<sub>The server in use is WildFly 10.0.0 final / Java EE 7.</sub>

Comment: I wonder what the security constraint has got to do with the concrete question. Question would still stand good when you leave out it.

Comment: I added that section as additional information because GlassFish (4.1) would work with URIs like `/Push/CartPush` even though `<url-pattern>/Push/*</url-pattern>` were excluded or removed from `web.xml`. WildFly on the other hand, would report `403` with `/Push/CartPush`, when that `<url-pattern>` was excluded from `web.xml`. I am unaware of the reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, WS URI template is [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpoint.html#value--) to follow [RFC 6570 **Level 1**] [2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2) templates. So a Level 3 template like `/Push/CartPush{/token}` won't work out.

Your best bet is always suffixing it with `/` and let the token be an empty string.

```
var token = "";
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/ContextPath/Push/CartPush/" + token);
```

It might be worth an enhancement request at [WS spec guys](https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC).

Given that the parameter is fully defined in the client, an alternative is to supply it as a request parameter. Naturally, request parameters represent client-defined parameters.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/ContextPath/Push/CartPush?token=" + token);
```

```
String token = session.getRequestParameterMap().get("token").get(0);
```